# Wrong tootip in chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to plot a graph with several time series in the same canvas. What I am doing is something just like this example https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/line.html

I need to show all the values in a specific time, so I add to the code the follow code chart option.

```
     options: {
        ...
        tooltips: {
          mode: 'index',
          intersect: 'true'
        }
     },
```

But the tootip is showing in wrong place.
Obs: the green line has less points that others, the tootip is showing the second x point for all curves not considering the same date/hour

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB71B.png)

Answer (score 0):

[`tooltips.mode: 'index'`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#index) finds items from different datasets that are at the same index each.

You should use [`tooltips.mode: 'x'`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#x) instead, it returns all items that would intersect based on the `x` coordinate of the position only.

```
options: {
    ...
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'x',
      intersect: 'true'
    }
},
```

> Please also have a look at the this [Chart.js samples](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/interactions.html) page, which illustrates the behavior of the different combinations of the options `tooltips.mode` and `tooltips.intersect`.